# How to do Dynamic dataframe indexing in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, dynamic

I have two dataframes; sauce and rules. rules has a column called fieldname which consists of column names present in sauce. rules has a row called fieldvalue which consists of fileds pertaining to the column name in sauce. I want to be extract data from sauce based on fieldname and fieldvalue of rules.

I was trying to use for loops but they take too long and have not been able to get the correct result out of it.

```
> sauce <- data.frame(Type = c("ketchup","mustard","mayo","lite-mayo","ketchup"), Brand = c("Heinz","Publix","Kroger","Kroger","Kroger"))
> rules <- data.frame(fieldname = c("Type","Type","Brand"),
                        fieldvalue = c("ketchup","lite-mayo","Kroger"),
                          operator = c("and","or",""),
                            fielname2 = c("Brand","Brand",""),
                             fieldvalue2 = c("Heinz","Kroger",""))
```

I am intending to index column names but using a different dataframe
`sauce[,c(rules$fieldname)]`

I am ideally wanting to get data out of sauce based on rules dataframe.

for instance: fielname: Type and fieldvalue: ketchup (and being the operator) should result in ketchup Heinz as the output

Comment: It'll help if you include the desired output.

Comment: I have updated the above dataframes as I realized they didnt paint a good enough picture. sauce has 200 records and 10 variables. rules has 40 records with the variables shown. The output I am trying to get are rows from sauce 1. where Type is ketchup and Brand is heinz, 2. where Type is lite-mayo or Brand is Kroger, 3. Brand is Kroger. So output will be: record 1 from sauce which is Ketchup Heinz, record 3,4,5 where lite-mayo or kroger exists, record 3,4,5 where Kroger exists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a vector of conditions using `apply` and `sprintf` from rules dataframe

   ```
   #Change and, or to &, |
   rules$operator_sym <- ifelse(rules$operator=="","",ifelse(rules$operator=="and",'&','|'))
   conds <- apply(rules, 1, function(x) if(length(x[x!=''])==6) 
     sprintf("%s == '%s' %s %s == '%s'", x['fieldname'], x['fieldvalue'], x['operator_sym'], x['fielname2'], x['fieldvalue2']) else  
     sprintf("%s == '%s'",x['fieldname'],x['fieldvalue']))

   > conds
   [1] "Type == 'ketchup' & Brand == 'Heinz'"    "Type == 'lite-mayo' | Brand == 'Kroger'"
   [3] "Brand == 'Kroger'"
   ```
2. Use `map` to loop through `conds` and `filter` *sauce* using the current condition. Use `parse_exprs` to transfer the condition from a string into R epression then evaluated using `!!!`

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   library(purrr)
   library(rlang)
   map(conds %>% set_names(), ~filter(sauce, !!!parse_exprs(.x)))

   $`Type == 'ketchup' & Brand == 'Heinz'`
        Type Brand
   1 ketchup Heinz

   $`Type == 'lite-mayo' | Brand == 'Kroger'`
          Type  Brand
   1      mayo Kroger
   2 lite-mayo Kroger
   3   ketchup Kroger

   $`Brand == 'Kroger'`
          Type  Brand
   1      mayo Kroger
   2 lite-mayo Kroger
   3   ketchup Kroger
   ```

Using `map` the output will be a list if you'd like the output as a dataframe you need `map_dfr(conds %>% set_names(), ~filter(sauce, !!!parse_exprs(.x)), .id = "Condition")`

Comment: I am getting the following error when running the map_dfr Error in parse_exprs(.x) : could not find function "parse_exprs"

Comment: @ZainA load `rlang` using `library(rlang)` and make sure you have `rlang>0.3.4`

Comment: @ZainA after I add `operator_sym` column, _rules_ will be with 6 columns instead of 5, hence I check if the non-empty columns i.e. `!=' '` are equal to 6 or not. e.g. consider row 1 and row 3 in _rules `length(rules[1,][rules[1,]!=''])==6` and `length(rules[3,][rules[3,]!=''])==6`

Comment: @a-suliman how would the conds statement change if rules had fieldname3, fieldvalue3 and operator1 as a third condition

Comment: i added the following already: `rules$operator1_sym <- ifelse(rules$operator1=="","",ifelse(rules$operator1=="AND",'&','|'))`

Comment: Do you have a situation where the 2nd condition is missing and the 3rd condition exists?. if it's possible to update your question with the exact scenario that you have.

Comment: No second condition only exists when first exists and third only exists if first and second exist. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Try `apply(rules, 1, function(x) if(length(x[x!=''])>7) sprintf("%s == '%s' %s %s == '%s' %s %s == '%s'", x['fieldname'], x['fieldvalue'], x['operator_sym'], x['fielname2'], x['fieldvalue2'],  x['operator1_sym'], x['fielname3'], x['fieldvalue3']) else if(length(x[x!=''])==6) sprintf("%s == '%s' %s %s == '%s'", x['fieldname'], x['fieldvalue'], x['operator_sym'], x['fielname2'], x['fieldvalue2']) else  
    sprintf("%s == '%s'",x['fieldname'],x['fieldvalue']))`